# Why are my Azure deployments to local IIS failing?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, iis

I'm deploying an asp.net core web app to local IIS 8.5 with an Azure pipeline. Deployments are failing because the .dll of the site is locked by IIS. This is despite the fact that I explicitly stop the site, using a IIS Web App Manage task, before the deployment.

The specific error is...

ERROR_FILE_IN_USE Web Deploy cannot modify the file'MyApp.dll' on the destination because it is locked by an external process

Why is this. What do I have to do to get IIS to release the .dll and let my pipeline do its thing?

[image]

**Update**

I've tried a powershell script to create a App_offline.htm file. The file's created, but the following Web App Deploy task still fails with the same error.

Comment: maybe something else is using the DLL?  Did you try manually stopping the site, and manually deleting the file?

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2021/Jun/20/Locked-Files-When-Publishing-NET-Core-Apps-to-IIS-with-WebDeploy and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-3/#shadow-copying-in-iis

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed it. I needed to stop the app pool in addition to the website. So in the **IIS web app manage** task, in **Additional appcmd.exe commands**, put

```
stop apppool /apppool.name:"MyAppPool"
```

[image]